# controller action being executed even after setting returnValue to False in function

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with one textbox and one button. Here I need to validate if users are not entering invalid data in the textbox so I have a function in site.masters "head" which is called "onclick" event. The issue is, even after setting the "returnValue" variable to "False" the controller action is being executed and I get the following error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'id' of non-nullable type 'System.int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddStudent(System.DateTime)' in
>   'Student.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult AddStudent(int id)
        {
            StudentDataContext student = new StudentDataContext ();

            var std = student.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentId == id);

                        std = new Models.Student() { StudentId = id};
                        student.Students.InsertOnSubmit(std);
                        student.SubmitChanges();
                        TempData["Message"] = "Student " + id + " is added";
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", TempData["Message"]);

       }
```

Here is my javascript code from Site.Master:

```
<script language="javascript">

    function verifyInput() {
        var returnValue = true;
        if (document.getElementById('studentId').length != 10) {
        returnValue = false;
        alert("please enter a valid id")
        Form1.studentId.value = "";            
                }
        return returnValue;            
    }

</script>
```

Here is my form code from my view:

```
<form id="Form1" method="get" action="/Home/AddStudent/" runat="server">
    <label for="id">
        <br /><br /> Student ID:
    </label>
        <input type="text" name="studentId" id="studentId" maxlength=10/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Student" onclick="verifyInput()"/>
</form>
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tsk tsk... You should be using [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your onclick event to:

```
onclick="return verifyInput();"
```

or

```
onclick="verifyInput"
```

Also, for form validation, you should be checking that on submit, instead of on click. That way you capture the miscellaneous times a form submits, such as when they hit the enter button.

It would be something similar to:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return verifyInput();">
```

Comment: I get an error when I try using "onsubmit", it says: "Attribute onsubmit is not a valid attribute of element input"

Comment: my mistake, I was using "onsubmit" in input element instead of form element. It is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to `return` returnValue.  Right now you're setting it to false, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: I still get the same error. I updated my code with  "return returnValue;" above. Could it be because I am calling action in my view? <form id="Form1" method="get" action="/Home/AddStudent/" runat="server">
Should I be calling my action in JavaScript instead? If so, I could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has something more to do with your Routes.  Does your default route, or the one for this action, look something like this?

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

If not, you will need to append the `studentId` to the end of your from action before submitting it.

maybe something like:

```
if (document.getElementById('studentId').length != 10) {
  ...false...
} else {
   document.getElementById('Form1').action = document.getElementById('Form1').action = document.getElementById('studentId').value;
}
```

Also, it may help to set maxlength as "10" instead of 10, wrapping it with quotes.